# How to convert console output to array php

Tags: php, console-application

How can we convert the console output to array in php to do further computation on the console output datas?

I have compile my matlab program in executable console based application. I want to use the output of the exe in php for computation without saving the output in a file I want to save it in an array. The matlab code is as follows

```
      [im_data,color_names,color_weight_vec_coarse,color_weight_vec_fine,shoe_grad_pyramid_shape,...
    shoe_grad_pyramid_texture,shoe_aspect_ratio,time_elapsed] = single_shoe_description_seq(im,...
    plot_option,save_option,canny_thresholds,phog_params,save_name_list,color_file_mat,num_clusters_emd);

disp(im_data)
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Columns 1 through 7

    0.1373 0.0414 0.0541 0.1342 0.5606 0.5293 0.1652

  Columns 8 through 14

0.0341 0.0396 0.0633 0.0778 0.0289 0.0654 0.0752

   Columns 15 through 21

  0.3055 0.4602 0.0631 0.0360 0.0188 0.0497 0.0228

  Columns 22 through 28

0.0294 0.0373 0.0734 0.3148 0.1703 0.0294 0.0057

Columns 29 through 35

0.0263 0.0382 0.0977 0.0396 0.1056 0.0781 0.1085
```

Comment: Can you give an  example of what you are trying?

Comment: What are you doing that outputs to console? Please post at least a bit of code.

Comment: Do you need the column values in an array? There are ways to do it of course. It would be easier if you change the output format of the matlab script to json or xml

Comment: Yes I need the column values in an array. As I know the output that I am getting from the console exe is in ASCII form I cannot do computation on it. So may be saving in an array can help. How can I change the output format of matlab to json or xml?

Answer (score 1):

It could have helpful if you had show us your output & expected output still you can try this one,

```
$output = shell_exec('your execute command');
$outputArray = split("[\r|\n]", trim($output));
print_r($outputArray);
```